# Use different welcome files for local and production

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets, web-applications, web.xml, welcome-file

We are running our web application successfully on the google app engine server.We are using index.html file
as a welcome file both in local and production environment. Now we want to use different welocme files for local and prtoduction.

I have seen the post: [web.xml with different files in welcome-file-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23800647/web-xml-with-different-files-in-welcome-file-list)
but will it work without having issues with ips?

May i know what is the procedure to do that? Any suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 1):

A welcome file is only used when no other handler is matched. If you want to test your app starting from `DevelopmentIndex.html`, all you need to do is hit

```
.../DevelopmentIndex.html
```

on your development server.

Comment: can you elaborate more on your answer please?

Comment: When you enter a URL with your domain in a browser, either the production or the dev server will go through the list of handlers mapped in web.xml file looking for a match. If a match is found, the request is sent to the corresponding servlet. If no match is found, the server serves the first file from the welcome list. Therefore, if you need to start your app from a specific file, all you need to do is append this file name to your domain in the browser.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, we have web-driver tests also to change the flow.In this case is it good way of doing it?